# displaying data retrieved from firebase using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to display the data i retrieved from firebase , ths retrieval is successful but it only displays one "Client"

here's the javaScript code :

```
    var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCHoJfq1lIph8gr4AQ0pTt2mClKzm06HlQ",
    authDomain: "contactform-4376b.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://contactform-4376b.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "contactform-4376b",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "497947572169"
    };
     firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');

    var query1=messagesRef.orderByChild('Nom_client');
    query1.on('value', gotData , errData);
    function gotData(data){
    event.preventDefault();
    var names = data.val();
    console.log(names);
    var keys =Object.keys(names);

      for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
          var k=keys[i];
             var Nom_Client=names[k].Nom_client;
             var Prenom_Client=names[k].Prenom_Client;
             var Age_Client=names[k].Age_Client;
             var Ville_Client=names[k].Ville_Client;
             var Tel_Client=names[k].Tel_Client;
             var Tel_Portable_Client=names[k].Tel_Portable_Client; 
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#but").click(function (){
       $("#0").html(Nom_Client+"</br>"+Prenom_Client+"</br>"+
       Age_Client+"</br>"+Ville_Client+"</br>"+Tel_Client+"
       </br>"+Tel_Portable_Client );

       });
       });
       }}

       function errData(err){
       console.log('error');
       console.log(err);
       }
```

This is my code, please feel free to suggest any change because i'm kinda new to javaScript , thank you
This is my database structure :

```
       newMessageRef.set({
       Nom_client:Nom_Client ,
       Prenom_Client:Prenom_Client ,
       Email_Client:Email_Client,
       Tel_Client:Tel_Client,
       Tel_Portable_Client:Tel_Portable_Client,
       Ville_Client:Ville_Client,
       Addresse_Client:Addresse_Client,
       Age_Client:Age_Client,
       Code_Postale_Client:Code_Postale_Client,
       Description_Client:Description_Client
        })
```

Comment: What exactly is the contents of your database that you're listening to at `/messages'?

Comment: Also, event.preventDefault() doesn't seem to have a purpose.  The Firebase callback doesn't provide a DOM event to deal with. And please fix the formatting of your code if possible.

Comment: i'm listening to all the data in my database:

Comment: Can you edit your question to post your database structure?

Comment: What's the value of `newMessageRef`?